# Subdomain htaccess rules

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following `.htaccess` in my root:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
Options +Indexes

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I want to add the following rule for everything under the /account folder:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

I believe it should start with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/account` but I'm not sure how to write the actual rule nor where in the document to add this.

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: I tried in /account/.htaccess :

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php

# Enable the rewrite engine in the subdirectory to prevent
# mod_write directives in the parent .htaccess file being executed.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit
```

Comment: The fastest and easiest way to do this is to create an .htaccess file within your /account directory with the rules you want.

Comment: @closetnoc, I tried this but it didn't work. When removing the whole Wordpress rule from the root `.htaccess` it affected the /account pages even though there is a custom `.htaccess` file in /account

Comment: Is `/account` intended to be _outside_ of WordPress? Simply including the `ErrorDocument` directive inside `/account/.htaccess` is not going to work because the WordPress mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file are going to override requests for non-existent-files (rewriting all requests to `index.php`). You either need to break the association with WordPress, for the `/account` folder, or incorporate alternative directives in the main `.htaccess` file - although this might not be so easy since WordPress normally handles 404s. What is the actual goal here?

Comment: Ah, I've just noticed the _title_! Is this really a _subdomain_?

Comment: @w3d, yes it's a subdomain. The subdomain is running a separate platform from wordpress (that I am coding) and I want that (sub)site to have a separate 404 behaviour than that of the wordpress site. -- sorry if I didn't make it clear it's a subdomain.

Answer (score 1):

If the `/account` subfolder is intended to be outside of WordPress then you can do something like closetnoc suggests, however, you also need to enable the rewrite engine to *prevent* the WordPress rewrites in the parent .htaccess from taking over.

So, in `/account/.htaccess`:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php

# Enable the rewrite engine in the subdirectory to prevent
# mod_write directives in the parent .htaccess file being executed.
RewriteEngine On
```

Simply enabling the rewrite engine in the subdirectory will prevent mod_write directives in the parent .htaccess file being executed. Since mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default. In order to "inherit" parent directives you would need to explicitly call: `RewriteOptions inherit`.

The fact that it's a subdomain doesn't really make a difference in this respect.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply @w3d, but this doesn't seem to work. I tried entering an incorrect url (`account.domain.com/index.phpp`) and (`domain.com/account/index.phpp`) but these yield different results.

The first one just loads `account.domain.com/index.php` and the second one takes me to the wordpress 404-page.

Comment: I edited my question to show what I tried in /account/.htaccess

Comment: Don't include `RewriteOptions inherit` (as you've included in your question) - that will certainly produce the results you are experiencing, which is not desirable is this instance. The bit I wrote about `RewriteOptions` was for background information only, you don't want to "inherit" the parent (WordPress) directives. Also, try an entirely incorrect URL eg. `/this-does-not-exist.php`.

Comment: Does `/index.phpp` _externally redirect_ to `/index.php`? - Not sure why that would happen, unless there is _something else_ going on?

Comment: The url in the browser still displays `index.phpp` but it definetly loads the default `index.php`.

Comment: Also note that `/error.php` will refer to different files depending on whether you are accessing this via the subdomain or the subdirectory. If via the subdomain then you will need `/account/error.php` and consequently the subdirectory will see `/error.php` in the main domains root. But generally, you should not be accessing both the subdirectory _and_ the subdirectory directly. If this is a problem then 301 the subdirectory to the subdomain.